# Number of instances of SAT (boolean satisfiability) problems of size N?

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I assume the size of an instance of the SAT problem is measured by its number of (Boolean) variables.  What is total number of instances of SAT problems of size N?

I guess that amounts to counting the number of "distinct" formulas that can be formed by N boolean variables, using a normal form such as CNF or DNF.

Update:  this question is partly answered for the 3SAT case:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2168/15553

and the number of distinct **clauses** is:
$$ C = 2N \times 2(N-1) \times 2(N -2) / 3! = 4 N(N-1)(N-2)/3 $$

Comment: What kind of logical operators are allowed? Do you know how to count words in *any* language?

Comment: What's the context where this problem arises? What's the motivation? Why do you care? How will you use the answer?  And.... what have you tried? We expect you to make a serious effort to answer the question on your own before asking, and to show us in the question what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I am temporarily too busy to think about this question, but I will update when I have time :)

Answer (score 6):

If you consider 3-Conjunctive Normal Form (3CNF) (every clause has exactly three literals) and you allow clauses with repeated variables, then it is easy to see that using $N$ variables the number of different 3SAT clauses is $(2N)^3$
($2N$ because every literal can appear unnegated or negated).

So the total number of distinct 3CNF formulas (without repeated clauses) is $2^{(2N)^3}$.

But be careful because the "size" of a 3CNF formula (e.g. considered as an input of a decision problem) is usually the size of its representation. For example, using alphabet $\Sigma = \{0,...,9,``,",-\}$
the 3CNF formula $(x_1\lor\bar{x}_2\lor x_3)\land (\lor x_2 \lor \bar{x}_3 \lor \bar{x}_4)$ can be represented with the string:

```
1,-2,3,2,-3,-4
```

and its length is 14.

Comment: What if there is a limit of the amount of clauses $C$?

Answer (score 5):

A clause is comprised of literals over **n** variables. Let us assume that an instance is a subset of *distinct* clauses. We can obviously calculate the number of instances as the powerset of clauses, but that requires us to first clarify what we consider a valid clause.

In general, each variable will either be *represented* by one or both of its literals, or else it will be *unrepresented*. If the variable is represented, it may be represented through the positive literal only, the negative literal only, or both. Since there are 4 possible cases for each variable, and **n** variables, there must be $4^n$ possible clauses. Excluding the null clause we have $4^n -1$ total clauses and, excluding the null instance, $2^{4^n - 1}-1$ possible instances.

Of course, clauses that contain both literals of any variable aren't particularly useful; each one is satisfied by every assignment. Since these clauses don't really add any constraints, let's restrict our attention to *constraining* clauses.

In doing so, we eliminate the possibility of any variable taking both its literals, so we're left with three possible cases per variable, or $3^n$ possible clauses. Excluding the null clause and null collection again, we have $2^{3^n - 1}-1$ possible instances.

For k-SAT, each clause has exactly k literals. Obviously, there are $n\choose k$ ways to select k variables. Since we need exactly k literals per clause, however, we can only represent each variable with its positive or negative literal only. Thus, there must be $2^k{n \choose k}$ k-clauses, and $2^{2^k{n \choose k}}-1$ instances of k-sat.

Finally, note that we can also determine how many instances contain exactly c clauses.

- For all possible clauses, excluding the null clause: ${4^n-1}\choose c$
- For constraining clauses: ${3^n-1} \choose c$
- For k-clauses: ${{2^k}{n\choose k}\choose c}$